# Call parallel multiple the api request in the clean architecture

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture

I have 5 api call function in the viewModel that I want to called parallel how can I do this? I put each of the function in the `WithContext(Dispachers.IO)` but it's not working. I used coroutines flow for calling api.
Note: I used clean architecture pattern and I have single use-case

**ViewModel codes:**

```
class MyJobsViewModel constructor(
    private val myJobsUseCases: MyJobsUseCases,
    private val clientNavigator: ClientNavigator
) : ViewModel(), ClientNavigator by clientNavigator {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(MyJobsState())
    val state: State<MyJobsState> get() = _state


    private fun getAllJobs(
        offset: Int = 0,
        limit: Int = 10,
        type: JobTypeEnum = JobTypeEnum.ALL
    ) {
        myJobsUseCases.getJobsUseCase.invoke(offset = offset, limit = limit, type = type)
            .onEach {
                when (it) {
                    is Resource.Success -> _state.value =
                        state.value.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            allJobItems = it.data ?: JobItemsResponse()
                        )
                    is Resource.Error -> _state.value =
                        state.value.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            error = it.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                        )
                    is Resource.Loading -> _state.value = state.value.copy(isLoading = true)
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    private fun getActiveJobs(
        offset: Int = 0,
        limit: Int = 10,
        type: JobTypeEnum = JobTypeEnum.ALL
    ) {
        myJobsUseCases.getJobsUseCase.invoke(offset = offset, limit = limit, type = type)
            .onEach {
                when (it) {
                    is Resource.Success -> _state.value =
                        state.value.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            activeJobItems = it.data ?: JobItemsResponse()
                        )
                    is Resource.Error -> _state.value =
                        state.value.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            error = it.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                        )
                    is Resource.Loading -> _state.value = state.value.copy(isLoading = true)
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to parallel multiple calls is to follow [structured concurrency principle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#structured-concurrency-with-async).

For example, when you need to evaluate the result of 5 independent network requests:

```
suspend fun fetchA(): Int { /* ... */ }
suspend fun fetchB(): Int { /* ... */ }
suspend fun fetchC(): Int { /* ... */ }
suspend fun fetchD(): Int { /* ... */ }
suspend fun fetchE(): Int { /* ... */ }

suspend fun overallResult(): Int = coroutineScope {
    val a = async { fetchA() }
    val b = async { fetchB() }
    val c = async { fetchC() }
    val d = async { fetchD() }
    val e = async { fetchE() }

    a.await() + b.await() + c.await() + d.await() + e.await()
}
```

Or when you need to make 5 independent api calls without returning any value:

```
suspend fun callA() { /* ... */ }
suspend fun callB() { /* ... */ }
suspend fun callC() { /* ... */ }
suspend fun callD() { /* ... */ }
suspend fun callE() { /* ... */ }

suspend fun makeCalls(): Unit = coroutineScope {
    launch { callA() }
    launch { callB() }
    launch { callC() }
    launch { callD() }
    launch { callE() }
}
```

Wrapping function in `launch` or `async` block produces a new coroutine and executes in parallel.

`coroutineScope` organizes the area where launch and async can be used. It completes only when every child coroutine is completed.